# How read a value in pl/sql procedure?

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedure

I am having problem regarding to **scan a value in a pl/sql procedure.** When I have execute the procedure, it ignores the **a:='&a';**.

**Procedure Body**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Testing
IS
a VARCHAR2(3);
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Enter a : ');
  a:='&a';
END Testing;
```

**Procedure Calling**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
cl scr;
Execute Testing;
```

**Output**

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Enter a :
```

Can anybody help me, please!?

Comment: What is your `define` setting (use `show` in SQL Developer to check)? PL/SQL isn't designed for user interaction, and prompting for values is unusual, and not really practical in a stored procedure. You certainly can't use `dbms_output` for the prompt because it is (as you can see) shown after the block execution ends. You can use the `prompt` and `accept` client commands, but not from within PL/SQL. Hard to tell what you will really want to do though.

Comment: I get your point, but **SHOW** command is not working. I've gone through [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/tools/rtoolsijcomrefshow.html).

Comment: That link isn't for Oracle Database; try [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve041.htm#sthref2258). And the [`set define` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIIEDF) to set it to `&`, if it is off.

Comment: Note that the '&' prefix for substitution variables is configurable in SQL*Plus (`set/show define`). More importantly perhaps, in your example all this is doing is prompting for a value that will be compiled permanently into the procedure (check the procedure source after compiling). PL/SQL runs in the database and is not interactive except as part of tools like Forms or Apex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL*Plus we have the prompt and accept syntax, but there is no direct way to make PL/SQL interactive without using PHP, Apex, Java, Scripting. I am giving you example of scripting.

e.g. In Windows batch, following code will help.

1) Code for the Testing procedure is same what you have

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  Testing (arg varchar2)
IS
a VARCHAR2(3);
BEGIN
a:=arg;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value of a : '||a);

END
```

2) test.bat

```
sqlplus nd211/nd211 @Testing.sql te1
sqlplus nd211/nd211 @Testing.sql te4
```

3) Testing.sql

```
set serveroutput on
exec Testing('&1');
exit;
```

Testing;
    /

4) Sample output

```
Value of a : te1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


Value of a : te4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question

Comment: Yeah! This is what I wanted to do. Thanks mate.